# Symbol filled with colour using tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf, symbols, draw

I am trying to reference data presented in figures in my text. In order to identify the data being discussed, I draw the symbol in the text.

I can use tikz to draw the circle that is filled with various color as shown in my MWE. I was wondering is there a way to draw other symbols like diamond, triangleright, square, square, triangledown or triangleleft in similar manner (please see the MWE)?

I was wondering if this is the right way to do this? Or is there an easier way?

```
\documentclass{article}
% draw circles
\usepackage{tikz,siunitx,gensymb}
\newcommand{\tikzcircle}[2][red,fill=red]{\tikz[baseline=-0.5ex]\draw[#1,radius=#2] (0,0) circle ;}%


\begin{document}

    This is a circle with pink filling and blue border (\tikzcircle[blue, fill=pink]{3pt}) \\
    This is a circle with red filling and black border (\tikzcircle[black, fill=red]{3pt}) \\

    I would like to have command like "tikzcircle" for more symbols such as $ \diamond , \triangleright $ or $\triangleleft$ for example. 
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The pgfmanual is *full* of shapes. Of course you could define symbols as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
% draw circles
\usepackage{tikz,siunitx}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric,shapes.symbols}
\newcommand{\tikzcircle}[2][red,fill=red]{\tikz[baseline=-0.5ex]\draw[#1,radius=#2] (0,0) circle ;}%

\newcommand{\tikzsymbol}[2][circle]{\tikz[baseline=-0.5ex]\node[inner
sep=2pt,shape=#1,draw,#2]{};}%

\begin{document}

\tikzsymbol{fill=blue}

\tikzsymbol[ellipse]{minimum width=8pt}

\tikzsymbol[rectangle]{minimum width=8pt,fill=yellow}

\tikzsymbol[diamond]{fill=purple}

\tikzsymbol[trapezium]{fill=purple}

\tikzsymbol[star]{fill=yellow}

\tikzsymbol[kite]{fill=blue}

\tikzsymbol[cylinder]{minimum width=5mm,minimum height=8mm,
cylinder uses custom fill, cylinder end fill=red!50,cylinder body fill=blue}

\tikzsymbol[cloud]{minimum width=8mm,minimum height=4mm}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I stress that this is only a tiny subset of the full set of possible shapes. However, I also think that on the long run you won't use such commands, but directly work with `tikz`, yet this is just a guess.

Answer (score 5):

As @marmot alludes to, there are many ways to create all sorts of shapes using Ti*k*Z, but I will address how I think it is best to implement these shapes to be used with text as you describe.

If you want additional customised symbols in the style of `\diamond` , `\triangleright` and `\triangleleft`, then the approach I would recommend would be to create the symbols using Ti*k*Z, but use `scalerel` to scale the symbols so they match the size of `\diamond` , `\triangleright` and `\triangleleft`. This way you don't have to worry about setting the size of the symbols each time and they will scale nicely with the size of the font. Here is an example:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{scalerel}

\setlength\parindent{0pt} % Turn off paragraph indentation for illustration purposes in MWE

\newcommand{\tikzcircle}[1][red,fill=red]{\scalerel*{\tikz \draw[#1] (0,0) circle (2pt);}{\circ}}

\newcommand{\tikzdiamond}[1][red,fill=red]{\scalerel*{\tikz \draw[rounded corners=0.06pt,#1] (-3pt,0)--++(45:3pt)--++(-45:3pt)--++(-180+45:3pt)--cycle;}{\diamond}}

\newcommand{\tikztriangleright}[1][red,fill=red]{\scalerel*{\tikz \draw[rounded corners=0.1pt,#1] (0,-2.5pt)--++(0,5pt)--++(-30:5pt)--cycle;}{\triangleright}}

\newcommand{\tikztriangleleft}[1][red,fill=red]{\scalerel*{\tikz \draw[rounded corners=0.1pt,#1] (0,-2.5pt)--++(0,5pt)--++(-180+30:5pt)--cycle;}{\triangleleft}}

\begin{document}

\tikzcircle[red], \tikzdiamond[blue, fill=pink], \tikztriangleright[red,fill=orange!50] or \tikztriangleleft[green!60,fill=yellow!50] \\
$\circ$, $\diamond$,  $\triangleright$ or $\triangleleft$\\

\Huge \tikzcircle[red],  \tikzdiamond[blue, fill=pink], \tikztriangleright[red,fill=orange!50] or \tikztriangleleft[green!60!black,fill=yellow!50] \\
$\circ$, $\diamond$,  $\triangleright$ or $\triangleleft$\\

\end{document}
```